# Increase distance between inner view and segmented control layer

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol

I have segmented control in my app. So far I make it like in image below:

[image]

Is there any way to change distance between layer of inner view (white view for selected segment) and layer of segmented control to make it like in the following image?

[image: image2]

Here is my code for segmented control:

```
private let segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {
    let control = UISegmentedControl(items: ["My likes", "Inbox"])
    control.backgroundColor = AppColor.segmented.uiColor.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
    control.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    control.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    return control
}()
```

P/S. I know that I am able to do it without segmented control but using buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I think best way to make custom View with buttons. Because this style of segment Control only available in ios 13+.